# What is the purpose of the dot between sqlalchemy joins

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to understand [this section of the SQLAlchemy documentation on Composite Secondary Joins](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#composite-secondary-joins). There is a dot operator between two joins that seems like I would expect it to be a comma. I'm thinking, if it isn't a typo, it might be an intersection operator, but I don't know. `secondary="join(B, D, B.d_id == D.id)."`  is the line. As you can see, there is a dot right before the double quote.

***What does this dot do?***

I extract the following code

```
    d = relationship("D",
                secondary="join(B, D, B.d_id == D.id)."  ### <-- What is this dot doing?
                            "join(C, C.d_id == D.id)",
                primaryjoin="and_(A.b_id == B.id, A.id == C.a_id)",
                secondaryjoin="D.id == B.d_id",
                uselist=False
                )
```

The full code is here:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_id = Column(ForeignKey('b.id'))

    d = relationship("D",
                secondary="join(B, D, B.d_id == D.id)."
                            "join(C, C.d_id == D.id)",
                primaryjoin="and_(A.b_id == B.id, A.id == C.a_id)",
                secondaryjoin="D.id == B.d_id",
                uselist=False
                )

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    d_id = Column(ForeignKey('d.id'))

class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'c'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(ForeignKey('a.id'))
    d_id = Column(ForeignKey('d.id'))

class D(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'd'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the arguments for [`relationship`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) can be passed as either a callable or a Python-evaluable string, for lazy evaluation at mapper initialization time. If a string, it is evaluated in a context that includes names from the metadata and Declarative class registry, and the `sqlalchemy` package – see ["Configuring Relationships"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/relationships.html#configuring-relationships) for details. This allows for example breaking some circular dependencies during class construction, etc.

Your [`secondary`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.secondary) argument is such a string, split to two lines. It is essentially as if you'd have used the expression

```
join(B, D, B.d_id == D.id).join(C, C.d_id == D.id)
```

as the argument (evaluated in the future), which should clear it right up: the dot is simply the dot from an [attribute reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references). The first join object is further joined with `C`, resulting in

```sql
B JOIN D ON B.d_id = D.id JOIN C ON C.d_id = D.id
```